# guice 3.0 injection

Tags: guice, code-injection

I have a LoginController that has field: @Inject ILoginService loginservice.

Google Guice is configured like this:

1. this creates injection of ILoginService

   ```
   bind(ILoginService.class).to(LoginService.class);
   bind(LoginController.class).toInstance(new LoginController());
   ```
2. this does not create injection of ILoginService

   ```
   bind(ILoginService.class).to(LoginService.class);
   bind(LoginController.class);
   ```
3. this does not create injection of ILoginService

   ```
   bind(ILoginService.class).to(LoginService.class);
   bind(LoginController.class).toProvider(new Provider<LoginController>() {

       public LoginController get() {
           return new LoginController();
       }
   });
   ```
4. does not work ... ILoginService is not injected

   ```
   @Provides
   public ILoginService loginService() {
       System.out.println("loginService");
       return new LoginService();
   }

   @Provides
   public LoginController loginController() {
       System.out.println("loginService controller");
       return new LoginController();
   }
   ```

Calling injector using: `injector.getInstance(LoginController.class);`

Comment: What's your question?  Also, my intuition would be that you mixed up #1 and #2 (I would expect #2 to work, but not #1).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume 1 & 2 are the wrong way round.

If you have `new LoginController()` in your Guice module (or anywhere else in your code) then Guice does not know to inject into it unless you tell Guice to do so by calling [Injector.injectMembers](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#injectMembers%28java.lang.Object%29) or [AbstractModule.requestInjection](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#requestInjection%28java.lang.Object%29).

Now why are you calling `new` in your code? What is it you want? If it is that only one instance of `LoginController` exists then use the Singleton scope.